# Coldfusion Importing CSV File Million Records causing performance issue..CFThread Works

Tags: multithreading, performance, loops, csv, coldfusion-9

i'm  importing almost one million records everyday, while importing doing filtering then adding in database table. It is causing performance issue some time loop stops on 9999.Is there a way i can do threading in loop?

is it a good idea to start million threads ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it a good idea to start million threads

Absolutely not. Even if you could open that many threads (which is doubtful) it is a terrible idea. Threads are not a cure-all. In this case, using them will only exacerbate the real problem, which is that looping is the wrong tool for this task.

Using a loop to import that much data is incredibly inefficient. Most databases provide tools specifically designed for the job of importing data in bulk. Those tools will perform MUCH, MUCH better than looping. You do not mention which dbms you are using, but some examples are MySQL's [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), SQL Server's [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) command, or as Scott mentioned in the comments, [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx). Import the data into a work table. (Break up the file into smaller chunks if needed, and process batches of say 100K rows at a time.)  Once the data is loaded, use SQL to filter/manipulate it in bulk and transfer it to wherever it needs to go.

Comment: im Using MSSQL 2008 Server & Application Server is Coldfusion 9

Comment: This is the only problem im getting flat text file.... if im breaking data in 100 rows so i have to load text file in memory it will cost me more ... :(

Comment: (Edit) Not one-hundred, one-hundred *thousand*. Exact size is up to you and what your environment can support. *RE: load text file in memory it will cost me more* While there are ways to improve file handling, are you saying that because you just *think* it will be worse, or because you have actually tried it? If not, try it first. Otherwise, update your question with your code.  Hard to believe spitting a csv could be worse than running a million individual queries and threads ...

Comment: Consider using the SQL Bulk Copy (bcp) command-line utility to import the data.  It will be much faster.

Comment: (Edit-typo fix) Yes, [bcp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) is another tool, probably better than bulk insert. Bottom line, any bulk loading tool is going to do a far better job than looping a million times...